# Trouble registering a GenServer with a via tuple. ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function PokerServer.whereis_name/1 is undefined or private)

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

Here's a very simple GenServer. I am trying to register it on initialization using a via tuple.

```
defmodule PokerServer do
  use GenServer

  def start(id) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, id, name: {:via, __MODULE__, id})
  end

  @impl GenServer
  def init(id) do
    {:ok, id}
  end
end
```

Unless I missunderstood something in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#module-name-registration), I should be able to pass the via tuple as a name in the third argument of GenServer.start/3

Except that when I try to start the process in the iex shell, I trigger an error

```
iex(1)> PokerServer.start(123)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function PokerServer.whereis_name/1 is undefined or private
(live_draft 0.1.0) PokerServer.whereis_name(123)
(stdlib 3.14.2.2) gen.erl:83: :gen.start/6
```

EDIT: I use elixir 1.12.3 and erlang/OTP 23

Comment: You are after `Registry` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html#module-using-in-via

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you pass in `{:via, __MODULE__, id}` should export `register_name/2`, `unregister_name/1`, `whereis_name/1` and `send/2`. For example:

```
def start(id) do
  GenServer.start(__MODULE__, id, name: {:via, :global, id})
end
```

> One such example is the `:global` module which uses these functions for keeping the list of names of processes and their associated PIDs that are available globally for a network of Elixir nodes. Elixir also ships with a local, decentralized and scalable registry called `Registry` for locally storing names that are generated dynamically. [Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#module-name-registration)

Comment: Here's an example of how [the registry module](https://github.com/sasa1977/elixir-in-action/blob/1b75c21f75c3a7c5ba1ad905a50b835ee64a395c/code_samples/ch09/dynamic_workers/lib/todo/process_registry.ex) would be implemented.